# How do I use a cumulative summing variable in a grafana query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, grafana

I'm setting up a combination of Grafana and MariaDB. One of my targets is to show a cumulative sum from values in a table as a Grafana time series.

I seem to need a summing variable in the SQL query.

Such a query **works**, if I enter it manually (e.g. in HeidiSQL) on the database. It does **not** work, when I take over the query scheme to the Grafana web interface.

**Example:**

I have a table like this

```
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Datum` DATE NOT NULL,
'Sachkosten` INT(11) NOT NULL
```

I want to show the cumulative sum of Sachkosten. It works manually on the database when I execute:

```
set @csum := 0;
SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Datum) as time_sec,
    Datum,
    Sachkosten as value,
   'Sachkosten' as metric,
   (@csum := @csum + Sachkosten) as cumulative_sum
FROM aufwand
ORDER BY Datum ASC
```

The above **works as expected directly on the database**: the fifth column is the cumulative sum of third column:

```
"1569801600"    "2019-09-30"    "-6000" "Sachkosten"    "-6000"
"1569801600"    "2019-09-30"    "35000" "Sachkosten"    "29000"
"1572220800"    "2019-10-28"    "-4000" "Sachkosten"    "25000"
```

When I enter the same in Grafana, I get errors around the use of the variable @csum. In the example above:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Datum) as time_sec,
Datum,
Sachkosten as value' at line 2
```

Do we have some hero here which knows, how to get such query variables working in Grafana? Or other ways do to that cumulative sum?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you cannot combine two statements in one query.  Try setting the variable in a subquery:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Datum) as time_sec, Datum, Sachkosten as value,
       'Sachkosten' as metric,
       (@csum := @csum + Sachkosten) as cumulative_sum
FROM aufwand CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @csum := 0) params
ORDER BY Datum ASC;
```

Or, perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Datum) as time_sec, Datum, Sachkosten as value,
       'Sachkosten' as metric,
       SUM(Sachkosten) OVER (ORDER BY Datum) as cumulative_sum
FROM aufwand CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @csum := 0) params
ORDER BY Datum ASC;
```

Note that in newer versions of MySQL, the `ORDER BY` may not affect the ordering of the cumulative sum.  You would need a subquery with the `ORDER BY` to ensure that.

Comment: Thanks! The first solution worked directly directly in Grafana.

(I only had to remove "Datum, " which could not work in Grafana. The sum worked directly after that).

Comment: @JanBrinkhaus Please set Gordon Linoff's answer with Mask as answer.